# How to solve the following differential equation $B'(t)=1100\exp({\frac{\ln{0.5}}{5}t})+\frac{\ln{0.5}}{6}B(t)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I have constructed this differential equation $B'(t)=1100\exp\left(\frac{\ln{0.5}}{5}t\right)+\frac{\ln{0.5}}{6}B(t)$

I have constructed this equation when i asked this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3021331/how-to-build-a-differential-equation-of-quantity-by-time-of-a-drug-that-is-in-th/3021343?noredirect=1#comment6230533_3021343),
but i'm unable to solve this equation from methods that i know.

I'm unable to  separate it, and it's not of the form $y'+p(t)y=q(t)$.

What should be done here?

Comment: why did you construct this differential equation?  (Hint: add context, like your motivation for asking the question, and why this particular question? Why is knowing how to proceed important to you wrt this particular DE?)

Comment: "it's not of the form $y'+p(t)y=q(t)$." Is it not? "What should be done here?" Look more carefully at the equation, perhaps.

Comment: I'm sorry but what do you mean. $\frac{ln(0.5)}{6}$ isn't a function of t

Comment: $q(t) $ in this case would be $1100\exp\left(\frac{\ln(0.5)}{5} t\right)$

Comment: Yes I've got it.

Comment: $\ln(0.5)/6$ is a constant function of $t$

Comment: But that is not the function $q(t)$ that is presented here, @MartínVacasVignolo, which was already addressed prior to your comment.  Before commenting, please read the question fully, then the comments, so you're not out of step with the process of helping the asker figure this out.

Comment: @user3133165  If you've gotten enough information from the comments to answer the question, why don't you go ahead and answer your own question, posted as an answer, below?  Of course you don't have to; but if you can take it from here, why not?

Answer (score -1):

The equation is of type $y'+p(t)y=q(t)$.

The solution for $B(t)$ will be $B(t)=\frac{\int{\mu(t)q(t)dt +c}}{\mu(t)}$,$\mu(t)=e^{\int{}p(t)dt}$.